# How to authenticate users using restangular?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express, mean-stack, restangular

I'm trying to create web application using MEAN in which i'm trying to authenticate users with the passwords they have created during signup. Below is how my signin.html looks like

```
    <div ng-controller ="MoviesSignCtrl">
  UserName</br>
  <input type="text" ng-model="movie.username" placeholder="Username">
  </br>
  </br>Password</br>
  <input type="password" ng-model="movie.password" placeholder="Password">
  </br></br>
  <input type="button" value="Login" ng-click="signFunction()">

</div>
```

I'm using restangular to connect my angularjs and node api

Below is my angularjs controller

```
angular.module('clientApp')
  .controller('MovieEditCtrl', function (
    $scope,
    $routeParams,
    Movie,
    $location
  ) {
    $scope.movie = {};
    Movie.one($routeParams.id).get().then(function(movie) {
      $scope.movie = movie;
      $scope.signFunction = function() {
        if($scope.movie.username.then(function() {
          $location.path('/movie/' + $routeParams.id);
        });
      };
    });
  });
```

But i know the above logic is wrong , can someone explain me how to check if the user exists in the database or not and then check if the password matches with the one in database.

Answer (score 0):

Your logic is unclear. What you actually need to do is send a userAuthorization object to your backend, which contains a username and password. You then check whether the username/password sent match what's in the db. If they do match, you send back whatever you wanted from the call to the front end, if they don't match, you send back an unauthorized error and handle it in the error part of the promise on the front end.

So, send three things to the backend - movie (your endpoint), movieId (your standard id for a REST get call), userAuthorization object (object holding username and password).

Overall, this is a poor way to do security in general, but I won't get into that since I understand that you are trying to handle it in a basic manner.